# Replace in a file with variable containing underscore

Tags: bash, shell, sh

### File Content(`file.txt`):

```
table=$table_name
data=$data_name
```

### Shell Script:

```
name=kush_123
cat file.txt | grep 'table' | sed "s\table_name\$name\g"
```

### Expected output:

```
table=$kush_123
```

This gives error

> unterminated `s` command

if the `name` variable has `_` in it.

Comment: Why are you using backslashes as the delimiter?

Comment: I have tried using # as well

Comment: Are you sure you tried using `#`? Because the error is definitely nothing to do with the `_`

Comment: @Inian I think that is just the content of a separate file, not a variable they are using.

Comment: sed "s#table_name#'$name'#g"

Comment: Why have you put random single quotes in the middle?

Comment: Tried removing that as well.

Comment: Well then it would work.

Comment: No i didn't worked

Comment: @Inian its not a variable

Comment: @kushagramittal: Can you post your exact expected output for your input? It is quite vague

Comment: Added in the question above.

Comment: @kushagramittal: What is wrong with just doing `sed "s|table_name|$name|" file.txt` ? it is working fine for me

Comment: Sorry guys found the issue the variable name had a trailing space. Thanks for help

Comment: No one has mentioned he's doing a cat->grep->sed, when sed would suffice.

Comment: Actually this was just an example to illustrate what i was trying, the scenario is actually lot complicated than this. @SaintHax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On more investigation i found out the variable name has trailing spaces as the variable value was passed from python code. I trimmed extra spaces and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a backslash as a delimiter, it needs to be escaped itself so that the double-quoted string preserves it before passing to `sed`:

```
sed "s\\table_name\\$name\\g"
```

Otherwise, `sed` receives the string `stable_name$nameg` as its script. (`\t`, `\$`, and `\g` expand to `t`, `$`, and `g`, respectively). In this case, the letter `t` (as it immediately follows the `s`) is used as the delimiter, and the error results because there aren't enough `t`s in the result to provide a complete command.

Of course, if you try this, `sed` should complain that a backslash cannot be used as the delimiter for the `s` command. Use a different character:

```
sed "s/table_name/$name/g"
```

In general, building such scripts dynamically is fragile, because it assumes you know the value of `$name` doesn't contain your chosen delimiter.

Comment: It isn't so the double quoted string preserves it, it's so that sed doesn't interpret it. You could do the same without any quotes.

Comment: @123 I mean, a single backslash in the double-quoted string escapes the following character, so a literal backslash itself needs to be escaped.